# How do I inform a user about a duplicate record exception in Rails/Sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I have a Sinatra application controller which creates a new record in a `Survey` table. Here is my ActiveRecord model which validates the `title` uniqueness -

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Initially, I only used `Survey.create` in my controller code, but it turns out Rails when a user enters a duplicate record, it identifies it as duplicate (due to the validation) but then selects that particular record and then continues with the routing. I don't want this to happen. Instead I wanted the user to know that the record exists and that an alternate survey title must be chosen. Here is the terminal output I had initially when I input 'Beverages' (a duplicate record) -

GET /surveys/new
  Query params: {}
  Requst body params: {}

POST /surveys/new
  Query params: {}
  Requst body params: {"survey_title"=>"Beverages"}

```
D, [--reda #1894] DEBUG -- :    (1.6ms)  BEGIN
D, [--redacted--- #1894] DEBUG -- :   Survey Exists (12.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "surveys" WHERE "surveys"."title" = 'Beverages' LIMIT 1
D, [--redacted--- #1894] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  ROLLBACK
```

To prevent this, I now have this code in my controller (is there better way to do this?) -

```
post '/surveys/new' do 
@survey = Survey.find_by(title: params[:survey_title])
if !@survey
    @survey = Survey.create(title: params[:survey_title], user_id: session[:user_id].to_i)
else
    # I want to add a message to the user here
    redirect '/surveys/new'
end
session[:survey_id] = @survey.id
redirect to  '/surveys/create'
end
```

Also, ideally, I would like to throw an alert message to the user via Javascript without having to route to a separate .erb view and then reroute them back to the page. I want the user to know that the title exists and hence the survey cannot be created. How do I do this? Should I raise an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There (a bit outdated) gems:
[rack-flash](https://github.com/nakajima/rack-flash) and [sinatra-flash](https://github.com/SFEley/sinatra-flash).

If they are too old to use, you can at least steal the idea from there.

Comment: [sinatra-flash](https://github.com/SFEley/sinatra-flash) was what i was looking for. and i get the general idea now. Thanks!